# Loading a Partial View inside a Parent View with two different models

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

My situation is simple, yet I haven't quite come up to speed yet on the technique for using a reusable dropdownlist partial view inside a parent view.

When my view tries to render (after retrieving the proper data), I get the following error message:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'YeagerTechDB.Models.Category', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Categories.CategoriesDDL'.
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
@Html.Partial("_SelectCategoryProjects");
```

I know what the error *means*, but don't know how to resolve it... I always thought as well, that a partial view can contain a different model than its parent view.

I would appreciate an answer very much as I'm obviously using this technique incorrectly.

### Model for my EnumDropDownListFor

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using YeagerTechDB.Enums;

namespace YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Categories
{
    [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class CategoriesDDL
    {
        [DataMember]
        public short CategoryID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public CategoryTypeEnum CategoryType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Partial View Contents

```
@model YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Categories.CategoriesDDL

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CategoriesDDL";
}

<div class="form-group">
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryType, new { @class = "control-label required pull-left col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" })
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryType, "Select Category", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

### Pertinent Controller code

```
// POST: Categories/CategoryProjects/Details
public ActionResult Details()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
// POST: Categories/CategoryProjects/Details/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(short id)
{
    if (id == 0)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Category category = await db.GetProjectsByCategoryIDAsync(id);

    if (category == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(category);
}
```

### Pertinent JS

```
function contentDetailsCatProjects()
{
    //var Url = $("#ddlCatProjects").val();

    $('#CategoryType').change(function (e)
    {
        getCatProjects();

        return false;
    });
}

function getCatProjects()
{
    var category_Input = {
        id: $('#CategoryType').val()
    };

    var Url = $("#categoryProjectsUrl").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: Url,
        data: JSON.stringify(category_Input),
        //data: AddAntiCSRFToken(JSON.stringify(category_Input)),
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (data, status)
        {
            if (status == "success")
            {
                //data retrieved
            }
        },
        error: function (data, status, xhr)
        {
            if (xhr == "Not Found")
            {
                bootbox.dialog({
                    message: "No Projects exist for selected Category!",
                    title: "Category",
                    buttons: {
                        danger: {
                            label: "Warning!",
                            className: "btn-warning"
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                bootbox.dialog({
                    message: "Projects cannot be retrieved for selected Category!" + '\n' + status + '\n' + xhr + '\n' + data,
                    title: "Category",
                    buttons: {
                        danger: {
                            label: "Danger!",
                            className: "btn-danger"
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

### Pertinent View Code

```
@model YeagerTechDB.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Categories";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>
    @Html.Partial("_SelectCategoryProjects");
</div>

@if (Model != null)
{ 
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Associated Projects for selected Category
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Project ID</th>
            <th>Project Description</th>
            <th>Project Name</th>
            <th>Quote</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Created Date</th>
            <th>Updated Date</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ProjectID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Quote)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Notes)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CreatedDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UpdatedDate)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.Hidden("categoryProjectsUrl", Url.Action("Details", "CategoryProjects", new { area = "Categories" }))
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            if (typeof contentDetailsCatProjects == "function")
                contentDetailsCatProjects();
        });
    </script>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial Views can reference models other than the parent model. See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.partialextensions.partial(v=vs.118).aspx) which describes the various overloads.

In your case, you will need a way to instantiate an instance of `CategoriesDDL` to supply `_SelectCategoryProjects` with the model it is expecting. There are perhaps many ways to do this, but I wouldn't suggest doing this as part `Details`. Depending on your situation, you might create an instance of `CategoriesDDL` on the fly or perhaps implement a static method that could provide an instance of the object.

To create on the fly, replace `@Html.Partial("_SelectCategoryProjects")` with `@Html.Partial("_SelectCategoryProjects", new CategoriesDDL {...} )`.

Or, use a static method...

```
public static class MyCategoryControl
{
   public static CategoriesDDL GetCategoriesDDL() { ...some code to return instance of CategoriesDDL.. }
}
```

Then, replace `@Html.Partial("_SelectCategoryProjects")` with `@Html.Partial("_SelectCategoryProjects", MyCategoryControl.GetCategoriesDDL())`

Answer (score 1):

You model for your main view is `Category`. By default when you use `@Html.Partial("_SelectCategoryProjects");` it passes the `Category` model to the method which generates the error. Either include a property in `Category` for `CategoriesDDL`, for example

```
public class Category
{
  ....
  public CategoriesDDL Categories { get; set; }
}
```

and in the main view

```
@Html.Partial("_SelectCategoryProjects", model.Categories)
```

Note you need to ensure that `Categories` is initialized (either in the controller or in a parameterless constructor), otherwise if its null, then the `Category` model will be passed instead of `CategoriesDDL`

Another option is to use call a child action which renders the partial view using `@Html.Action()`